# Integral over momentum space of the distribution function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, notation, integration, calculus

I have $$\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}p\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = \int \frac{d^2\hat{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\int^\infty_0 p^2dp\ p \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} ,$$ where $f$ is the distribution function, $\hat{p}$ is the unit momentum vector, $p$ is the magnitude of the momentum vector.

How do I get from the left hand side to the right hand side of the above equation?

Comment: It is not clear what the rhs means here (what is $\hat{p}$?): shouldn't it be just a transformation to spherical coordinates?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: In other words, it is spherical coordinates - the double integral is over a unit sphere with constant density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we've written ${\rm d}^3p$ in spherical coordinates.  The volume element in 3D momentum space is
$${\rm d}^3p=p^2\sin\theta\;{\rm d}p\;{\rm d}\theta\;{\rm d}\phi$$
and it looks like they've condensed the angular part into
$$\sin\theta\;{\rm d}\theta\;{\rm d}\phi\equiv{\rm d}^2\hat{p}$$